# KnockoutJS - Can we have Observable Function call for CSS updates

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a ticketing system which is written in KnockOut using template. Template structure is as below This template is repeated for multiple users on a page. In this parent.AssignedTickets is a list of Ticket Id assigned to users.

```
<script type="text/html" id="TicketAssignmentTemplate">
<td>
   <label data-bind="css: {success: $root.getCheckStatus(TicketId, $root.AllAssignedTickets)}">
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: TicketId, checked: $parent.AssignedTickets" />
    </label>
</td>
<td>
    <label data-bind="text: title"></label>
</td>
self.getCheckStatus = function (itkID, ListID ) {
    if (ListID.indexOf(itkID)>= 0)  
       return true;
    else 
       return false;
}
```

```
<style>.success{background-color: #DFF0D8;}</style>
```

So system has multiple TicketIDs and if it is assigned to user by checking the check box, parent.AssignedTickets gets updated and I update root.AllAssignedTickets, both of which are observable arrays. Now I want to change label color of checkbox which gets updated by getCheckStatus(TicketId, $root.AllAssignedTickets).

Can the function be made observable to update CSS real time when checkbox is checked or unchecked?

Comment: <script type="text/html" id="TicketAssignmentTemplate">
    <td>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: TicketId, checked: $parent.AssignedTickets" />
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label data-bind="text: title"></label>
    </td>
</script>
<script>
self.getCheckStatus = function (itkID, ListID ) { if (ListID.indexOf(itkID)>= 0) return true; else return false; }
</script>

<style>.success{background-color: #DFF0D8;}</style>

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're passing `AllAssignedTickets` as a parameter. If you do it like this:

```
self.getCheckStatus = function (itkID) {
    return self.AllAssignedTickets.indexOf(itkID) > -1;
}

<label data-bind="css: { success: $root.getCheckStatus(TicketId) }">
```

Knockout will create a subscription internally, and it'll work fine.